# Element deletion causes wrong click in Selenium

Tags: c#, html, selenium, browser-automation

When selenium tries to click a button, web site deleting a div above, and selenium clicks the element under the element that I wanted to click.
I try to click with XPath, CSS selector, and the class name and none of them work. Also, I tried action chains to click but not worked.

And before clicking, I can confirm the selected element is the right element.

> `var element=driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("warning"))[0];` 
> `Debug.WriteLine(element.Text);`

This writes the right element to the output.

-Here is the code By.ClassName:

> `driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("warning"))[0].Click();`

The element under the right element does not have a "warning" class but it's still clicking on that element.

The page is basically like this:

```
<div id="maindiv">
<div class="the div that will delete"></div>
<button class="warning"></button>
<button class="second"></button>
<button class="third"></button>
<button class="fourth"></button>
</div>
```

[here is how its looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKfrq.png)

Basically, I'm trying to click the "warning" button but the "third" button receiving the click.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. First I deleted the div before clicking, then I clicked the button.
Here is the code:

```
var element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//[@id=\"app\"]/div[7]/main/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]"));
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].parentNode.removeChild(arguments[0]);",element );

var button=driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"app\"]/div[7]/main/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/span[1]/span/button"));
((IJavaScriptExecutor) driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();",button);

     `
```